# What flow control mechanism does ethernet uses?

Tags: ip, tcp, mac

Datalink layer is basically responsible for 3 major functions -

```
Error detection/correction - CRC is used by ethernet
Collision detection - CSMA/CD is used by ethernet
```

But I couldn't find what flow control mechanism does ethernet protocol uses?

Comment: Ethernet flow control is poorly implemented and supported, and it does not have error correction. Flow control is mostly in the transport layer.

Comment: Does that mean in standard home ethernet the entire responsibility of flow control is given to the transport layer?

Comment: @AtharwaAdawdakar since 95-99% of home traffic is TCP, yes. And TCP has much better flow control than Ethernet.  BTW, home networking is off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethernet has two methods:

1. Pause frames (802.3x and 802.1Qbb)
2. Priority flow control (802.1p)